# Material UI in React JS - Tabs re-renders on switching

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am just starting in ReactJS and have a very basic doubt which I can't seem to work around without manipulating some complex things which I don't yet understand (according to some answers here)

Here is a brief example of my problem -

I have a specific implementation, where the "{console.log('Test log')}" inserted in this code snippet from the official page of Material UI, should not be logged on tab Switching. Currently, every tab switch, logs it in the console.

In the actual code, I have a function call at the place of console.log, which I don't want to perform on tab switching, currently, every time I switch any tab, it makes a function call because currently rendering the tab component basically means calling that function again and again. This is official publicly available Material UI code where I have added just a console.log. I can't actually post the code implementation due to privacy restrictions.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

function CustomTabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

CustomTabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

export default function BasicTabs() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="basic tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
      <CustomTabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </CustomTabPanel>
      <CustomTabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
       {console.log('Test Log')}
      </CustomTabPanel>
      <CustomTabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </CustomTabPanel>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I have tried changing these settings while making the Tabs component, but they also don't seem to work :

```
<Tabs
    
    unmountOnExit={true}
    mountOnEnter={true}
    transition={false}>

{children}

</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When should the special function be executed?

1.) If you want your code to be executed on switching to specific tab, you can do your call inside `handleChange`:

```
const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
  if(newValue == 1) {
    console.log('Test Log')
  }
  setValue(newValue);
};
```

2.) If you want to call it once (on the first render of your component), you can use [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) with an empty dependency list:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
...
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Test Log')
}, [])
```

3.) If you want to call it every time a specific state of your component changed, you can give [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) the state as a dependency:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
...
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Test Log')
}, [myState])
```

3b.) Conditionally load a component by a function when a specific state changed, store it another state and render it:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  const [ExternalComponent, setExternComp] = useState<React.FC>()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (counter % 2 == 0) {
      var comp = getExternalComponent(`Counter value: ${counter}`)
      setExternComp(() => comp)
    }
  }, [counter])

  const increment = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={increment}>{counter}</button>
      <p>{ExternalComponent && <ExternalComponent />}</p>
    </>
  )
}

const getExternalComponent = (text: string): React.FC => {
  return () => {
    return <div>{text}</div>
  }
}

export default MyComponent
```

Comment: Tried this as well. So basically, the index value assigned to tab 2 is = 1. If I make a call and check if the value is 1, it will always make that call whenever it switched to tab 2. This does reduce the number of times the function is called. But still calls it every time I switch to tab 2 from any tab

Comment: So i don't know if this makes sense in implementation, but the function that is placed inside tabs, returns a <Box> component which is basically saying, if you pass a value to that function, it will return a Box component which is then rendered. So, my main goal is, that function should not pass that value again & again every time I switch tabs. It should pass that value only when the value changes.

Comment: Where is the value stored where you want to execute the function again if you change it? If it is a state of your component, you can give `useEffect` the state and the function is executed every time the specific state is changed.

Comment: This is the structure currently:  function(stateVariable) This function is being called on every switch of tab. I want it to be called just when the stateVariable value is changed

Comment: Thats exactly the use case for the third option.

Comment: Unsure to re-render after getting the updated component from our functions. For example you can save your component in another state and update it inside useEffect via the set method. That will trigger a re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Add an option to `CustomTabPanel` called `onFirstShow`. If `onFirstShow` exists, the tab is not hidden, and it wasn't shown before (using a ref to track), the `onFirstShow` function is called:

```
function CustomTabPanel({ children, value, index, onFirstShow, ...other }) {
  const shown = useRef(false);
  const hidden = value !== index;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!shown.current && !hidden && typeof onFirstShow === 'function') {
      onFirstShow();
      
      shown.current = true;
    }
  }, [called, hidden, onFirstShow]);

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {!hidden && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And then use it when rendering the `CustomTabPanel`:

```
  <CustomTabPanel 
    onFirstShow={() => console.log('Test Log')}
    value={value}
    index={1}>
    Item Two
  </CustomTabPanel>
```